# How can I avoid generating the same number using a random number generator that I am assigning to two variables?

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

```
var randomDescriptor1 = descriptors[getRandomIndex(descriptors)];
  tagline1.innerText = randomDescriptor1;
  var randomDescriptor2 = descriptors[getRandomIndex(descriptors)];
  tagline2.innerText = randomDescriptor2;
```

```
function getRandomIndex(array) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
}
```

I am altering an HTML file using dom and want to generate random descriptors in the same sentence. I pull from an array of stored strings, but sometimes they happen to return the same word twice in the sentence. How could I avoid this?

Comment: You could shuffle the array and take the first/last 2 entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
const desc = Object.assign([],descriptors)
var randomDescriptor1 = getRandomDescriptor(desc);
  tagline1.innerText = randomDescriptor1;
var randomDescriptor2 = getRandomDescriptor(desc)
  tagline2.innerText = randomDescriptor2;

// you can delete have used item, you will always get a new one

function getRandomDescriptor(array) {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
  const value = array[randomNum]
  array.splice(randomNum, 1)
  return value
}
```